# Cable running across top of trusses

Tags: electrical, attic

I've got some cables in my attic that run across the top of my trusses. This white one goes to my dryer and is stapled every few feet. (The green cable is currently not attached to anything at either end.) Is it a hazard to have cables running along the top my attic? Or is it safer because no one is stepping on it?

I'm considering moving my dryer outlet because it's too far away from the washer. I'd like to properly run the cable through the attic in the process if if this wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have, or plan to have, an appropriate amount of insulation in the attic, running wires or cables down low hides them and you won’t easily find them later. If they’re up high they may be in the way, but I think the ones you show in your picture are high enough that they’re well out of the way. Do either high or low; don’t do anything in between that will make it hard to move around the attic.

You also mentioned the green cable has nothing on either end. If that’s the case, why not just remove it?